# Choosing between Google Cloud Flexible or Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, saas

I'm starting to build a web/mobile app that is going to be offered as SaaS.
I have seen many cloud options for hosting (Heroku, AWS) but finally decided to go with Google Cloud App Engine.

My back-end will be Java based, and I'm confused about going with the Standard or Flexible Env.
I have read several docs online but still undecided.

*Considerations to tackle:*

1. I am not very experienced with Docker and this is my first Saas App.
2. My app should run perfectly with the offering of the Standard Env.
3. Migrating from the Standard to the Flex environment seems to bring
   some headache.

Would you please help me decide on the way to?

Comment: I am also going through the same process.. My clarification to you .. are you planning to have your Server based database as MySQL ??

Comment: Yes i am planning to use MySQL through Google Cloud Db

Comment: @goofyui, u'll go with which approach and why? can you elaborate?

Comment: Related (if not even a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691466/google-app-engine-standard-or-flexible-environment/39064913#39064913

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We try to cover the key differences in this doc:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments

To cover your considerations:

1. You don't need to understand Docker to use flex or standard
2. If your app can run in Standard - that's great!
3. Migrating from Standard to Flex is a fair bit of work.  We try to cover it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/migrating)

Read over those docs, and let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hello Justin, Thank you. I have previously had a look @ the docs and will re-read them. Just one note, My app is not running in standard env, but its technical architecture would allow it to do so. So I am not sure if i start the dev using the stnadard or flexible env api.

Comment: Same here. Can I just overwrite the "env: flex" to standard if my app supports this?
Thank you

Comment: Mostly.  You can delete the line that says `env: flex` from `app.yaml` all together.  You may need to update the `runtime` field to be `runtime: nodejs10`, as standard requires an explicit version in the runtime name.